# requestLocationUpdates crashes

Tags: android, gps, android-2.2-froyo

I am still kinda new to android programming, and am running into an issue with the "requestLocationUpdates". I am pretty sure I have narrowed it down, to this, because my code works when I comment it out.  What happens is when I run it with the code as written below, the program just stops responding.  I am using android 2.2, with permissions set to 1.6.  I know 2.3 was causing issues, but it sounded like 2.2 should be fine.  I just included what I think was important in my code below, if other parts are need let me know.

```
    locman= (locationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locman.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManger.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, new locationListener());
}

private class locationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override  
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)  
    {  
        if (loc !=null) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location Changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + "Lng: " + loc.getLongitud(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }  
    gp= new GeoPoint(
        (int) (loc.getLatitude()*1E6),(int) (loc.getLongitude()*1E6));
```

Comment: Please post the logcat exception you see when the crash occurs

Comment: I'm presuming its not the spelling mistake loc.getLongitud() as your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: here the logcat with the last 4 lines when it crashes:
11-18 14:40:38.136: DEBUG/dalvikvm(305): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6213 objects / 383296 bytes in 62ms
11-18 14:40:39.976: DEBUG/dalvikvm(305): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11936 objects / 829776 bytes in 60ms
11-18 14:40:40.566: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
11-18 14:40:40.616: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4509bb30 msum.arch/.maplst}
11-18 14:40:41.986: DEBUG/dalvikvm(305): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6161 objects / 371768 bytes in 57ms
I checked, and yes it is spelled correctly.

Comment: still working on debugging this.  If i change from "LocationManger.GPS_PROVIDER" to ".NETWORK_PROVIDER"; it starts to work for me as in the map comes up with a predefined location, however I am unable to pass it new coordinates using the emulator from eclipse.  I checked my mainifest.xml and I am set to use both coarse and fine locations.  Any new ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it was a stupid mistake, on the manifest.xml file I spelled ACCESS with an extra S so it was ACCESSS.  Obviously does not work very well.  I hate spelling errors!  I figured it out, by adding COARSE_LOCATION, and realizing that FINE and COARSE did not line up correctly like they should.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe given loc parameter is null which would make new GeoPoint creation to fail?

Comment: forgive me, im new at android, but have some programming experience, but unfortuantly I am not seeing what you are.  I check to see, if anything has changed if it has changed then return the location.  Other whys it should look for the new location.